# Pass secure SSM parameter to a nested CloudFormation stack

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, ssm

I have a nested CloudFormation stack template that describes database and it's related resources. I need to create multiple databases for various environments (e.g. `stage`, `qa`, `prod`).

I store database password for each environment in SSM parameter store as secure strings, e.g.:

- `/acme/stage/DB_PASSWORD`
- `/acme/qa/DB_PASSWORD`
- `/acme/prod/DB_PASSWORD`

I've tried to resolve the SSM parameter in parent template and pass it to a nested stack, but it looks like it's not working.

```yaml
# parent.template

StageDatabaseStack:
  Type: AWS::CloudFormation::Stack
  Properties:
    TemplateURL: "…/database.template"
    Parameters:
      DatabasePassword: '{{resolve:ssm-secure:/acme/stage/DB_PASSWORD:1}}'

QaDatabaseStack:
  Type: AWS::CloudFormation::Stack
  Properties:
    TemplateURL: "…/database.template"
    Parameters:
      DatabasePassword: '{{resolve:ssm-secure:/acme/qa/DB_PASSWORD:1}}'

ProdDatabaseStack:
  Type: AWS::CloudFormation::Stack
  Properties:
    TemplateURL: "…/database.template"
    Parameters:
      DatabasePassword: '{{resolve:ssm-secure:/acme/prod/DB_PASSWORD:1}}'


# database.template

AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"

Parameters:
  DatabasePassword:
    Type: String

Resources:
  Database:
    Type: AWS::RDS::DBInstance
    Properties:
      MasterUserPassword: !Ref DatabasePassword
```

This approach gives me an error:

> An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the CreateStack operation: SSM Secure reference is not supported in: [AWS::CloudFormation::Stack/Properties/Parameters/DatabasePassword]

---

According to [the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/parameters-section-structure.html#aws-ssm-parameter-types), it is also possible to define password parameter as a special `AWS::SSM::Parameter::Value<String>` type, but it is stated, that:

> AWS CloudFormation does not support defining template parameters as SecureString Systems Manager parameter types.

I've actually tried to use it, but it gives me an error:

> Parameters [/acme/stage/DB_PASSWORD] referenced by template have types not supported by CloudFormation.

---

SO, how do I actually pass secure database password to a database resource in this scenario? I want to use a single CloudFormation template to manage all three databases and their related resources.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way to pass a secure SSM parameter to a nested stack I've found is to pass it as a string, instead of trying to use more sensible `AWS::SSM::Parameter::Value<String>` and then resolving the secure value in a nested stack by building the dynamic reference with `!Sub` function.

Here's a working example:

```yaml
# parent.template

StageDatabaseStack:
  Type: AWS::CloudFormation::Stack
  Properties:
    Parameters:
      DatabasePasswordSsmKey: "/acme/stage/DB_PASSWORD:1"

ProdDatabaseStack:
  Type: AWS::CloudFormation::Stack
  Properties:
    Parameters:
      DatabasePasswordSsmKey: "/acme/prod/DB_PASSWORD:1"
```

```yaml
# database.template

Parameters:
  DatabasePasswordSsmKey:
    Description: SSM property key for database password
    Type: String

Database:
  Type: AWS::RDS::DBInstance
  Properties:
    MasterUserPassword: !Sub "{{resolve:ssm-secure:${DatabasePasswordSsmKey}}}"
```

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
'{{resolve:ssm-secure:/acme/stage/DB_PASSWORD:1}}'
```

I.e. with apostrophs. See [YAML examples in the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/dynamic-references.html#dynamic-references-ssm-example.yaml):

```
  MyS3Bucket:
    Type: 'AWS::S3::Bucket'
    Properties:
      AccessControl: '{{resolve:ssm:S3AccessControl:2}}'
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, good catch, I did miss the single quotes. But now the error is the following: `An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the CreateStack operation: SSM Secure reference is not supported in: [AWS::CloudFormation::Stack/Properties/Parameters/DatabasePassword]`.

Comment: @SlavaFominII Ok, then try to declare a parameter of type `AWS::SSM::Parameter::Value<String>` and specify `/acme/qa/DB_PASSWORD:1` as `Default`. Then use this parameter in `AccessControl`. See [Integrating AWS CloudFormation with AWS Systems Manager Parameter Store](https://aws.amazon.com/de/blogs/mt/integrating-aws-cloudformation-with-aws-systems-manager-parameter-store/). We use this for AMI ids.

Comment: Just tried this, I'm getting the same error mentioned in my question: `Parameters [/acme/stage/DB_PASSWORD] referenced by template have types not supported by CloudFormation.`. By the way it's `MasterUserPassword`, not `AccessControl`, however, I don't think it matters in this case.